# Does completely reducible implies irreducible

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras

I was reading about representation of lie algebra;.We know, If a representation is irreducible that implies completely reducible. What about converse. does completely reducible implies irreducible? any examples

Comment: Nope: these two concepts are not equivalent. As an example, consider the direct sum of two irreducible Lie algebras.

Answer (score 0):

By definition, the direct sum of two irreducible representations of a Lie algebra $L$ is completely reducible, but not irreducible. Note that Weyl’s Theorem says that any finite dimensional representation of a semisimple Lie algebra $L$ over a field of characteristic zero is completely reducible.